# How do I remove the bad cast HINSTANCE to int?

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, casting

I'm compiling a program on gcc by using `-Wbad-function-cast` flag. The gcc show the following warning:

`cast does not match function type`

this is line of warning:  `int ret = (int)`[`FindExecutable(file, NULL, result)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The question is: it's possible remove it? maybe casting to another windows data type, but that I handling it as an integer.

Comment: Why do you need to cast it at all? Write the code like this: `HINSTANCE ret = FindExecutable(...);` or even `auto ret = FindExecutable(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked to see what HINSTANCE actually is?  (I'm guessing its a pointer, not an int).  So you will probably have better luck casting to a void*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

A handle to an instance. This is the base address of the module in memory.
HMODULE and HINSTANCE are the same today, but represented different things in 16-bit Windows.
This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
typedef HANDLE HINSTANCE;

HANDLE
A handle to an object.
This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
typedef PVOID HANDLE;

A pointer to any type.
This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
typedef void *PVOID;

Comment: @Jack, so you can (and probably should) remove the cast and make ret a void*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [FindExecutable documentaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-findexecutablea) the function returns an `HINSTANCE` type value, but also integers with values less or equal to 32 to indicate errors.  Casting the result to `int` on a 64-bit Windows system will trigger a compiler warning.  To avoid it and still check for error values, you can cast its value to `unsigned long long`.